# how do I get my ubuntu to boot

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I recently decided to install Ubuntu as a second option for running my system. When I went to install it I placed it on a drive that is connected via a usb However when i boot up there is no option to go to that drive and it goes strait to windows instead How do I get it to give me an option to boot to ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the boot order in BIOS. http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/change-boot-order-xp-vista/ should explain it. Your USB port probably is set lower on the list, so your hard drive always takes precedence.